# iPhone 4 Won’t Turn On or Wake Up?

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake

My lock button is broken and i have been using assist to lock my iPhone , but early today i pull my iPhone out of my pocket it I couldn't turn it on. I tried plugging it into the wall charger, nothing. I Tried plugging it up to my Mac , NOTHING and I'm not on a plan so I cant't get a new iPhone . So what do I do, I'm desperate for answers on how to fix this .

Comment: Does iTunes recognize it as an iPhone?

Comment: No @RedEagle2000

Comment: It may be the battery. Have you tried a different USB cable?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it sounds like your iPhone 4 has had it. If iTunes can't recognize it, then something is seriously wrong. The only thing I can think of is that the battery got disconnected, but that's not likely. The best thing to do is to sell "For Parts or Repair" on easy to pay for part of a used iPhone, but older models can be pretty inexpensive. A used iPhone 4 should cost only about  $75-$100, while a 4S should run $110-$130, a 5 for about $200, and an iPhone 5S for about $350.

Comment: Actually, before you sell it, have you tried to connect it with other charging cables?

Comment: No i will try though